# How to configure a maximum duration of an application session in Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, session-management, tomcat8.5

I need to configure a maximum duration of an application session in Tomcat to 24 hours.

I was not able to find the appropriate configuration in the documentation:

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html

(There is `sessionTimeout` for `SSLHostConfig` but I need the `Connector` configuration; We terminate the SSL connection in the WebServer before Tomcat but the session management handled by Tomcat.)

**Added**

We already handled the session expiration timeout ([Tomcat Session Timeout web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13463036/tomcat-session-timeout-web-xml)).

The maximum duration timeout means that even the user active during all time its application session will be invalidated after the maximum duration timeout.

Comment: Do you mean https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13463036/tomcat-session-timeout-web-xml?

Comment: No. I have updated the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HttpSessionListener` will only notify session creation and destruction but won't be invoked on each page request.

I'd implement a filter to check on session creation time and invalidate the session plus set headers or redirect.

In web.xml add:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Max Session Duration</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.your.package.MaxSessionDurationFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <!-- Maximum session duration in hours -->
        <param-name>maxduration</param-name>
        <param-value>24</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

and a mapping like

```
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>Max Session Duration</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Then the filter implementation is like:

```
package com.your.package;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class MaxSessionDurationFilter implements Filter {

    private final long oneHourMillis = 1000*60*60;

    private long maxDuration;

    private FilterConfig filterConfig;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig fc) throws ServletException {
        filterConfig = fc;
        maxDuration = Long.parseLong(filterConfig.getInitParameter("maxduration"));
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpReq = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse httpResp = (HttpServletResponse) resp;
        final long creationTime = httpReq.getSession().getCreationTime();
        final long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (currentTime-creationTime > maxDuration*oneHourMillis) {
            httpReq.getSession().invalidate();
            // Could also set headers to 403 forbidden
            // httpResp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
            httpResp.sendRedirect("expiredsession.jsp");
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, resp);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() { }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to implement `HttpSessionListener` and to destroy sessions after 24 hours:

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html

The question if exists better approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure maximum duration session using [setMaxInactiveInterval](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setMaxInactiveInterval(int))

> Specifies the time, in seconds, between client requests before the servlet container will invalidate this session.

Update when session created, using [HttpSessionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960764/how-to-set-session-timeout-dynamically-in-java-web-applications) overriding `sessionCreated` method:

```
public class MyHttpSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener{
  public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event){
    event.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(24*60*60); //24 Hours
  }
```

> use a HttpSessionListener. In the sessionCreated() method, you can set the session timeout programmatically.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not asking about the session expiration timeout.
We have configured  the session expiration timeout via `web.xml` `<session-config> <session-timeout>`

We need to invalidate the session even we have requests all time.

Comment: @Michael you can add WebFilter and set `setMaxInactiveInterval` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39564955/http-session-how-to-configure-urls-that-not-change-the-session-expiration

Comment: Thanks, but setMaxInactiveInterval is not what I need. I do know the solution using WebFilter and  HttpSessionListener.
Question if you know other sollutions

Comment: @Michael if you save in DB login time, you can have a schedule task which finds users logged in over a day and invalidate their session

Comment: thanks! this is exactly approach described in my answer

Comment: @Michael you can put and remove user session in `ConcurrentHashMap` in a singleton session handler