# How to force session out TOMCAT server after 5 hours(not inactivity session out)

Tags: java, tomcat8

How to force session out TOMCAT server after 5 hours(**not in inactivity**) 
tomcat version using : 8.5.46

Comment: With the Tomcat Manager?

Comment: @user207421 : programmatically or from tomcat manager is also fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

similar as [How to configure a maximum duration of an application session in Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54124724/how-to-configure-a-maximum-duration-of-an-application-session-in-tomcat)

You can add a filter and check session create time upon each request, and invalidate it if it's over 5 hours.